# Can't connect to IPv6-only host from java

Tags: java, httpclient, osx-yosemite, ipv6

I have some IPv6-only hosts. I can successfully execute curl request to it
by curl

```
$ curl -I my.ip.v6.only.host
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But when I trying to get it from java I have an error:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://my.ip.v6.only.host");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Stack trace:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to {}->http://my.ip.v6.only.host: No route to host
Mar 17, 2015 7:42:23 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://my.ip.v6.only.host
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:25)
```

Problem has been occured on java v1.7.0_65 and v1.8.0_40, MacOS 10.10.2. On previous version MacOS 10.9.5 it works well.

What's going on? How it is possible that host is reachable by `curl` and unreachable from java.

Also, I've tried to play around `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true` and `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false` and it couldn't help.

**UPD** found a related bug in OpenJDK, [JDK-8015415](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015415?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

**UPD 2** when I tried to use wired connection instead of wifi, it helped me. Weird.

Comment: What version of Apache Http Client are you using?

Comment: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5

Comment: Tried normal Java NIO requests yet? I can't seem to recreate this issue on a Linux box atm.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, of course host in online, because it is available with curl.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be problem in AirDrop + Java cooperation.

Short answer - try:

```
$ sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
```

Investigation of the problem below (thanks for Sergey Shinderuk):

We have such code in java to reproduce:

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Socket("2a02:6b8::3", 80); // ya.ru
    }
}
```

And when we use WiFi, get exception: `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`

While with telnet all ok:

```
$ telnet 2a02:6b8::3 80
Trying 2a02:6b8::3...
Connected to www.yandex.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
```

When we turn off wifi, and use wired connection - all ok. But if we used wired connection, but wifi is turned on - this java code won't work. Which is very strange.

We need to compare arguments for the `connect(2)` between java and telnet.

```
$ sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::connect:entry { print(*(struct sockaddr_in6 *)copyin(arg1, arg2)) }' -c './telnet 2a02:6b8::3 80'

struct sockaddr_in6 {
    __uint8_t sin6_len = 0x1c
    sa_family_t sin6_family = 0x1e
    in_port_t sin6_port = 0x5000
    __uint32_t sin6_flowinfo = 0
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr = {
        union __u6_addr = {
            __uint8_t [16] __u6_addr8 = [ 0x2a, 0x2, 0x6, 0xb8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x3 ]
            __uint16_t [8] __u6_addr16 = [ 0x22a, 0xb806, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x300 ]
            __uint32_t [4] __u6_addr32 = [ 0xb806022a, 0, 0, 0x3000000 ]
        }
    }
    __uint32_t sin6_scope_id = 0
}
```

You can see that we have printed second argument of `connect(2)` as struct  `sockaddr_in6`. Also you can see all expected info: `AF_INET6`, port 80, and ipv6-address.

> Make a note: we've launched `./telnet`, not `telnet` - `dtrace` can't
>   work with system binaries signed by Apple. So we should copy it.

Same for java:

```
$ sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::connect:entry { print(*(struct sockaddr_in6 *)copyin(arg1, arg2)) }' -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java Test'
[...]
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    __uint8_t sin6_len = 0
    sa_family_t sin6_family = 0x1e
    in_port_t sin6_port = 0x5000
    __uint32_t sin6_flowinfo = 0
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr = {
        union __u6_addr = {
            __uint8_t [16] __u6_addr8 = [ 0x2a, 0x2, 0x6, 0xb8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x3 ]
            __uint16_t [8] __u6_addr16 = [ 0x22a, 0xb806, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x300 ]
            __uint32_t [4] __u6_addr32 = [ 0xb806022a, 0, 0, 0x3000000 ]
        }
    }
    __uint32_t sin6_scope_id = 0x8
}
```

As we can see, the main difference is that telnet sends `sin6_len == 0` but java -  `sin6_scope_id = 0x8`. The main problem in exactly `sin6_scope_id`. telnet and curl sends `scope_id == 0`, but java - `0x8`. And when we use wired connection, java sends `scope_id == 0xb`.

To be clear, we try to reproduce problem with `scope_id` with telnet.
Using WiFi do:

```
$ telnet 2a02:6b8::3%0 80
Trying 2a02:6b8::3...
Connected to www.yandex.ru.

$ telnet 2a02:6b8::3%8 80
Trying 2a02:6b8::3...
telnet: connect to address 2a02:6b8::3: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

$ telnet 2a02:6b8::3%b 80
Trying 2a02:6b8::3...
Connected to www.yandex.ru.
```

So telnet can connect with `0xb`, but can't with `0x8`.

It seems that right place of this code for java is:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8fe85977d5a6/src/solaris/native/java/net/net_util_md.c#l105

We've seen that `scope_id` filled with value of private field java.net.NetworkInterface.defaultIndex, which contains index of some default interface.

We can print all indexes with code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<NetworkInterface> netins = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface netin : netins) {
            System.out.println(netin + " " + netin.getIndex());
        }

        Field f = NetworkInterface.class.getDeclaredField("defaultIndex");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("defaultIndex = " + f.get(NetworkInterface.class));
    }
}
```

On wifi:

```
$ java Netif
name:awdl0 (awdl0) 8
name:en0 (en0) 4
name:lo0 (lo0) 1
defaultIndex = 8
```

On wired

```
$ java Netif
name:en4 (en4) 11
name:lo0 (lo0) 1
defaultIndex = 11
```

On wired+wifi

```
$ java Netif
name:awdl0 (awdl0) 8
name:en4 (en4) 11
name:en0 (en0) 4
name:lo0 (lo0) 1
defaultIndex = 8
```

When wifi connected, `defaultIndex == 8`, and default interface is awdl0.

So we just

```
$ sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
```

and java code works.

Also:

- [WiFriedX](https://medium.com/@mariociabarra/wifriedx-in-depth-look-at-yosemite-wifi-and-awdl-airdrop-41a93eb22e48) can help.
- Another issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132520
- What is awd: [What is AWDL (Apple Wireless Direct Link) and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587701/what-is-awdl-apple-wireless-direct-link-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Linked to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26878#comment=27-1069340

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! Unfortunately, there's cases where bringing down `awdl0` isn't enough. On my MacBook, my `defaultIndex` points to `en5`, the full list being: en5, utun2, utun1, utun0, awdl0, en0, lo0; where en0 is the one that must be used. Quite painful. Interestingly, Java does already know how to do it right, if you use `SocketChannel.open(inet6SockAddress).socket()` you'll get a working socket. Of course, there's _tons_ of Java code that uses the standard `Socket` API, so this seems like a huge problem for IPv6 on Mac.

Answer (score 8):

The author of this patch is https://github.com/snaury.

Explanation:

You need to open libnet.dylib with otool and find _setDefaultScopeID symbol:

```
otool -tv -p _setDefaultScopeID libnet.dylib
```

Here you can find comparison with 0 and conditional jump:

```
000000000000b882    cmpb    $0x1e, 0x1(%r14)
000000000000b887    jne 0xb8aa
000000000000b889    cmpl    $0x0, 0x18(%r14)
000000000000b88e    jne 0xb8aa
```

You need to replace conditional jump to unconditional jump with any hex editor:

```
000000000000b882    cmpb    $0x1e, 0x1(%r14)
000000000000b887    jne 0xb8aa
000000000000b889    cmpl    $0x0, 0x18(%r14)
000000000000b88e    jmp 0xb8aa

JNE == 75 1a
JMP == eb 1a
```

Or use this one line command:

```
otool -tv -p _setDefaultScopeID libnet.dylib | awk '/cmpl.*\$0x0/ {print $1}' | python -c 'exec """\nwith open("libnet.dylib", "r+b") as fd:\n    fd.seek(int(raw_input(), 16) + 5)\n    fd.write(chr(235))\n"""'
```

Comment: Many thanks for one-liner! SHould be mentioned that libnet.dylib should be in jre path similar to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libnet.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

Wired connection helps me too.

With

`$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem yesterday. I solved it by overriding DNSResolver of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

```
    private static DnsResolver getDnsResolver() {
        return host -> Arrays.stream(InetAddress.getAllByName(host))
            .filter(it -> it instanceof Inet6Address)
            .toArray(InetAddress[]::new);
    }

////////

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
        RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .build(),
        getDnsResolver()
    );
```