# Show active interfaces in terminal

Tags: bash, macos-sierra

I am trying to list network interface that I am currently using. I need to know how to do this in terminal, and in script.

```
ifconfig | grep $(networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep 'Ethernet, Device' | sed -E "s/.*(en[0-9]).*/\1/")
```

What am i getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSNdn.png)

What do I want to get:
Only the name of active interface

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: This commands that appear higher, are these that I tried to use, but they didnt work.

Comment: What was wrong with them? I tried them on my Mac, I just had to change `Ethernet` to `Wi-Fi`.

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail. Say what result you're trying to get, and what you got instead. Edit the question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: How can I modify them, so they only show the name of active interface?

Comment: easy to say... haha...

Comment: **Edit the question, don't put it in comments.**

Comment: Show the result you're getting, then show what you want instead. PLEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your second command, but put everything after the interface name into a lookahead, so it's not printed as part of the match.

```
ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '^[^\t:]+(?=:([^\n]|\n\t)*status: active)'
```

When I do this, the output is:

```
en0
awdl0
```

See [What is AWDL (Apple Wireless Direct Link) and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587701/what-is-awdl-apple-wireless-direct-link-and-how-does-it-work) for what `awdl0` is.

Your first command should work if just print the result of the `networksetup` pipeline, without using `ifconfig`. This works for me:

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep 'Wi-Fi, Device' | sed -E "s/.*(en[0-9]).*/\1/"
```

I have Wi-Fi rather than Ethernet.

Comment: Second command doesn't work. It says: -bash: pcregrep: command not found

Comment: I'm not sure how I got it, but see https://superuser.com/questions/301435/is-there-a-command-in-mac-os-x-that-can-perform-multiline-regex-searching

Comment: This command from link also doesn't work. It says: -bash: brew: command not found

Comment: [How to install Homebrew](http://osxdaily.com/2018/03/07/how-install-homebrew-mac-os/)

Comment: I just find these things with google, can't you do that yourself?

Comment: Nvm, I got it now.

Comment: Why this command:

`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep 'Wi-Fi, Device' | sed -E "s/.*(en[0-9]).*/\1/"`

shows only interface `en1`

when this command:
`ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '^[^\t:]+(?=:([^\n]|\n\t)*status: active)' `
shows this: 
`en1
p2p0`

Comment: What's wrong with that? You only have one Wi-Fi card.

Comment: `p2p0` is used for AirDrop. It's not a network interface, it's a virtual network.

Comment: Yes, but why the second one shows me this p2p0 interface? I assume it's AirDrop. But why first command doesn't show it? They're supposed to show the same result...

Comment: `networksetup` only shows hardware devices, not virtual networks.

Comment: `networksetup` shows the same things you see in the Network system preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `scutil` command to show active interfaces and their IPv4/6 addresses (though it doesn't show the AWDL interfaces):

```
scutil --nwi
```